# Magento 2 Custom UPS shipping rates

Tags: magento2.2, shipping-methods

The client wants to use custom UPS Shipping Rates for different continents:

For instance:

1. EU: 20 euros
2. US: 30 euros
3. Asia: 40 euros

Is it possible to setup custom rates in Magento for UPS and then also ensure that UPS tracking etc. continues to work? Any useful extensions for this?

Thanks!